# Inserting vector into sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I have value I need in v[0] which is in vector v. How do I insert into the values portion of insert statement in c++ where I am going to run the code on a putty connected to unix. I tried values("v[0]"). Please help!!

```
    vector<string> v;
    //cout << "OK";
    ifstream input("artist.txt");
    while (!input.eof())
    {

        char ch;

        //while (!input.eof())

        string sample1;
        string sample;
        //cout << "OK";
        //input >> sample;
        //cout << sample;
        getline(input, sample, '|');
        string fina = sample;
        //input >> sample;
        //cout << sample << " ";
        getline(input, sample1, '\r');
        string fin = sample1;
        //cout << sample1;
        v.push_back(fina);
        v.push_back(fin);
        //string sample1;
        //string sample2;
        //cout << " ";
        //string sample1;
        //getline(input, sample1);
        //input >> sample1;
        //input >> " ";
        //input >> sample2;
        //cout << sample1 << " " << sample2 << endl;
        //cout << sample1;
        //string fin = sample1 + " " + sample2;
        //cout << fin;
        //cout << fina1;
        //v.push_back(fina1);
        //input >> sample1;
        //cout << sample1;
        //v.push_back(sample1);
        //cout << sample1;
        //cout << endl;

        //cout << v[0] << endl << v[1];
        //cout << vi[0] << vi[1];
        //v.push_back(fin);
        //input.seekg(2L, ios::cur);
        input.get(ch);
    }
    cout << v[0] << " " << v[1];

    sql1 = "INSERT INTO Artist(name) "  
        //"VALUES (" + quotesql(v[0]) + "," + quotesql(v[1]) + ");";
        "VALUES ("v[1]");";
        input.close();
    }
```

Comment: Please show what you *actually* tried (the whole command).

Comment: Ignore the comments just focus on the sql1 insert statement

Comment: Please tag your question with the language you are using. If the commented code is irrelevant, then remove it. Don't use string concatenation on SQL queries; use query parameters.

Comment: Ah, so this is c++ program?  You should search for "sqlite c++ parameterized queries"